# COUNTIF + MATCH WITH DATA

Tags: excel

I've got a problem and can't really figure it out the formula.
I really hope You gonna understand what I'm trying to say.

I have a sheet which is called: Leave Tracker, in Row 7 i've got dates.
[image]

Then i have a second sheet which is called: Daily Staffing.
The formula showed below counting me how many 'FT' codes are in column that matches with DailyStaffing B2.

```
{=COUNTIF(INDEX('Leave Tracker'!$B$9:$NI$485,0,MATCH($B$2,'Leave Tracker'!$B$7:$NI$7,0)),"FT")}
```

[image]
Then i have a 3rd sheet thats called Employee Data, where i have all data of my users.
[image]

So i've figured it out how to count how many users are matching criteria (date and code "FT"), but  I need to add a second criteria which is gonna be "CORE" from sheet Employee Data.

Any ideas how to solve it? I was trying to add a second INDEX,MATCH but as an output im getting only REF or SPILL.

Thank You all in advance! :)

Comment: Please include your formula in a code sample. Having it alone in a screenshot makes it hard to provide quick and clear answers. Secondly, you may want to look into COUNTIFS for multiple criteria.

Comment: Hi David, Post is updated. I know how to use COUNTIFS for multiple criteria, but i think  its not what im looking for, as i have to match it with other data as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

Adjust `'Leave Tracker'!$A$9:$A$20` and `'Employee Data'!$A$2:$H$20` to your full range of users

```
=SUMPRODUCT(('Leave Tracker'!$B$7:$NI$7=$B$2)*('Leave Tracker'!$B$9:$NI$485="FT")*(LOOKUP('Leave Tracker'!$A$9:$A$20,'Employee Data'!$A$2:$H$20)="core"))
```

Comment: Hi Matt, { =SUMPRODUCT(('Leave Tracker'!$B$7:$NI$7=$B$2)*('Leave Tracker'!$B$9:$NI$485="FT")*(LOOKUP('Leave Tracker'!$A$9:$A$144,'Employee Data'!$A$2:$H$144)="CORE")) } unfortunetly again my outpout is REF.

Comment: Check there are no #REF errors in `'Leave Tracker'!$B$9:$NI$485`, and ensure that the size of the arrays are the same i.e. based on your comment above try `=SUMPRODUCT(('Leave Tracker'!$B$7:$NI$7=$B$2)*('Leave Tracker'!$B$9:$NI$144="FT")*(LOOKUP('Leave Tracker'!$A$9:$A$144,'Employee Data'!$A$2:$H$144)="core"))` and no need to enter as an array formula either